# Trustful references about A* algorithm

Tags: algorithm, reference, shortest-path, maze

I'm working in a scientific article about some algorithms that can solve a maze, the A* can do this job by modifying the original code. I tried to find goods references about it, without success. there are others algorithm that I found trustful references without so much difficult, but the A* modified to find the shortest-path in a maze is really hard to find...

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Show the (pseudo) code you have, and where you have a problem.

Comment: Not sure you are looking in the right way. Because, what you have to find with A* is a good heuristic, algorithm is the same.

Comment: A* is nasty to search for because it's both short and not very significant, but if you honestly can't find any explanation of it whatsoever, then you must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This page is actually first page for on google when searching for A* references, so i've returned now I have found something. Eventually I came across its first description in an IEEE Journal.

> Hart, P. E., N. J. Nilsson, and B. Raphael (1968) A Formal Basis for
>   the Heuristic Determination of Minimum Cost Paths in Graphs. IEEE
>   Trans. on Systems Science and Cybernetics, Vol. SSC-4, No. 2, pp
>   100-107.